# How can a relationship be U-shaped when both linear and quadratic terms are positive and significant?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, poisson-regression

I have a predictor variable that ranges between 0-1, transformed to natural log due to multicollinearity and modeled with fixed effect negative binomial. Both the linear (B=9.9, St Error = 2.71, p<0.001) and quadratic (B=307.45, St Error=89.81, p<0.01) terms are positive and significant. However, plot of predicted values using mean values of all variables shows a U-shaped relationship. The Lind & Mehlum's (2010) Utest also confirms a U-shape with significant negative and positive slopes and turning point within the data range. However, theory as well as usual interpretation of linear and quadratic terms suggest that the relationship should be increasingly positive but the predicted values and Utest show a U-shaped relationship with significant negative slope at lower bounds and significant positive slope at the upper bound. It is a bit puzzling. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong or how to explain these results?

Comment: You took a natural log due to multicollinearity?

Comment: That is correct, Dave. Natural log transformation substantially reduced nonessential multicollinearity.

Comment: Transformations of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take logarithms of a variable that ranges between 0 and 1, the transformed values will all be negative.  For negative numbers, a positive quadratic coefficient means a negative slope.  So the quadratic equation is consistent with your plots and the test for U-shapedness.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, Thomas. You spotted the problem correctly. The left half of the U is less than zero while the right half is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

1. Plot all cases’ observed (Y-axis) vs. predicted ( X-axis) values without bringing in means in any way. Please post this plot here.
2. Try to think not in terms of “U-shaped or not” but rather of degree. For example, to what degree does the addition of a quadratic term increase predictive accuracy?
3. Are you able to crossvalidate to test these effects?